# How can i edit an embed every 10 seconds in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, i am trying to make a bot that pings my minecraft server and shows the players on it. I want to be able to start and stop it with "!" commands. I´ve got the main thing working but i dont really know how i can edit the embed every 10 secs or so. Im using discord.js. I thought about somehow calling the editing function every 10 seconds but i dont really see a function which i could call. Also the discord.js documentation doesnt help really much, because its mostly outdated, and many things changed, from what i could see. Also i should probably say that the codes pretty messy, so sorry for that. Here's my code so far:

````
const client = new Discord.Client()
const mcping = require('mc-ping-updated');
var server_players_num;
var server_players_name = [];
var server_players_max;
var server_version;
var embed;
var x = 0;
var fields = {};
//INSERT IP AND PORT BELOW
var serverip = "";
var serverport = 16400;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)
})
bot_secret_token = ""




function serverping() {
    mcping(serverip, serverport, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            // Some kind of error
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            // Success!
            console.log(res);
            server_players_num = res.players.online;
            console.log(server_players_num);
            server_players_max = res.players.max;
            if (server_players_num > 0) {
                x = 0;
                while (x < server_players_num) {
                    server_players_name.push(res.players.sample[x].name);
                    console.log(server_players_name[x]);

                    fields.name = "Spieler:";
                    if (x == 0) {
                        //fields.value = server_players_name[x];
                        fields.value = "[" + server_players_name[x] + "]" + "(https://mcuuid.net/?q=" + res.players.sample[x].id + ")";
                    } else if (x > 0) {
                        fields.value = fields.value + '\n' + server_players_name[x];
                    }
                    x++
                }
            };
        }
    }, 3000);
};
serverping();






client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === '!start') {
        // inside a command, event listener, etc.
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#d2ff00')
            .setTitle('Minecraft Server Status')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.ibb.co/hg8nG1s/HTL-PB.png')
            .addField("Spieler online:", server_players_num + "/" + server_players_max, true)
            .addFields(fields)
            .setTimestamp()

        embed = await message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);

        await embed.edit(exampleEmbed);






    }

});
client.login(bot_secret_token)```
````

Comment: The [Discord.JS](https://discordjs.guide/) guide and [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) are both constantly being updated along with newer versions. Also, editing a message every 10 seconds is way too frequent, making a bot do x every y is generally a bad idea. All of these API calls may get you [Ratelimited](https://mobile.twitter.com/discord/status/1072027291801317377?lang=en) which could lead to account suspension.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)
    setInterval(serverping, 10000); //10000ms = 10s
})
```

A piece of advice, if you want your bot to work asynchronously with other functions, a 10-second delay may be too fast. 1-2 minutes is enough for *most* occasions.

Comment: alright, so i guess its better if i only edit the embed when the players on the server change. How can i edit the message out of another function? Because thats mainly my problem

Comment: The easiest method I can think of is you can pass that message as a parameter to your other function.

Comment: @JoelRupp: Check every 10s if the players changed from the last state (stored in an array), and if so, update it,